# Remove author info from my facebook share function

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want peopel to share my posts via facebook's share pop up window, i just want to change the info that is written in the link on facebook.
Im using a custom post type, and removed the vcard info fro the post template.
here is FB's share JS:

```
<script>
    function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width='+winWidth+',height='+winHeight);
}
</script>
```

and this:

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>', 'Fb Share', 'Facebook share popup', 'http://goo.gl/dS52U', 520, 350)">Share</a>
```

When it is posted to facebook, it shows the Title, content, author, post date, link and image.

I would prefer it only posts the title and link with no author or content. Any ideas while i continue researching this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did  strip 'descr' fro the function didn't work, it was still written in the post

Answer (score 0):

Posts made prior to removing the descr show the author everytime, post made after descr was removed